# Could you please tell me where I would find the output for the mapreduce program Wordmedian in hadoop? Is it stored in a directory in HDFS?

Tags: hadoop, mapreduce, hdfs

Is this the right command?

`hadoop jar /usr/jars/hadoop-examples.jar wordmedian [input.txt] out`

Comment: Can you include some more details of the Hadoop job and your environment?

Comment: Basically I just want to compute the wordmedian of a given text document stored in HDFS and I'm using Cloudera QuickStart VM which runs on VirtualBox software.

Answer (score 0):

The format for submitting job is

`$ bin/hadoop jar wc.jar WordCount input output`

So when you are submitting any job like above, you need to mention your output directory along with input directory.

Yes, the final output of the job result will be saved in HDFS (mentioned directory)

Comment: Thanks for your response.